# Jquery div to div load only works in opera

Tags: jquery, load, opera, href, attr

Couple of days ago I found some solution for my problem here on stack. Here is the code:

**HTML**:

```
<a class="link" data-toggle="modal" href="link1.php" >Link 1</a>
<a class="link" data-toggle="modal" href="link2.php" >Link 2</a>
<a class="link" data-toggle="modal" href="link3.php" >Link 3</a>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal"></div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("a.link").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").html($(this).attr("href")); 
    /*$("#myModal").load($(this).attr("href"));*/
    return false;
});​
```

But, this only works in Opera. In every other browser the link is never opened inside `mymodal` div.
FULL CODE HERE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
#prvidiv {
    width:360px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: cool_font, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#0000CC;
    background-color:transparent;
}
#levideookvir{
float:left;
width: 760px;
height:800px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top: 0px;

}
</style>
<script src="jqery/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.link").click(function(e){
        $("#levideookvir").html($(this).attr("href")); 
       $("#levideookvir").load($(this).attr("href"));
       window.alert('Request complete');
         e.preventDefault();

  })
 });​
    </script>

<div id="prvidiv">
Ovde ide link<br />
<a class="link" href="test2.html">Klikni me</a><br />
</div>
<div id="levideookvir" >OVDE REY</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As its strange...I dont even get ALERT that I define when run this script in Chrome, Safari or FF. 
As I said...only work in opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.html()` method accepts only a HTML string as the parameter. You have the correct syntax in your code, but it's commented out.

Here's what you need (if I understood the question correctly):

```
$("a.link").click(function(e) {
    $("#myModal").load($(this).attr("href"));
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Comment: Nope... :(Not working.
I know about that commented part of code, it was not commented in my code. 
Where do I put it wrong?
I will paste whole code in new comment

Comment: I must add....whatever I try there is same result. 
Only OPERA can load data into defined DIV.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise...
Here is the code (naturally I dont use both code block at once so this is not a mistake)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
<!--THIS ONE IS WORKING-IT CAN BE OPENED IN ANY BROWSER   -->
 $("a.link").click(function(){
    $("#levideookvirsrcamoga233").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
    });
    });
//THIS ONE BELLOW IS NOT WORKING
    $("a.link").click(function(){
    $("#levideookvirsrcamoga233").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;

});​
});
</script>
```

RESOLVED! Changing charachter set while writing code on my keyboard was the problem.